# How do I access a returned value from a .ajax request within the done() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

Here's my function which returns a name of a person.

```
function getName(ID){
    return $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data: ID,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

And here is where I am attempting to use the .done() function.

```
getName("1").done() // How do I ref the returned var in our done function?
```

I am confused on how to reference the returned value from my getName function within my done function.

I know I could do this using success: within the .ajax, but I am trying to move away from that and used deferred objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it look slike done requires a callback function that takes a parameter with the data recieved from teh request.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
getName("1").done(function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Ah, I wanted to actually do something like this

getName("1").done(buildRow(nameReturned)); so I have to use an anon function?

Comment: I think you can use any function that takes 1 param `function buildRow(nameReturned) {}` should work fine. `getName("1").done(buildRow(nameReturned))`

Comment: Ah ok, so we reference the value returned from getName() by any name we would like in the done() function? I may be misunderstanding, but that seems a little odd.

Comment: @dm03514 Actually, when JSON or XML etc. is returned, your "`nameReturned`" (or `foo`...) variable might actually be an object and not "just" a simple string. Have a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types)

Comment: @yes hopefully it will have some structure and not be a string, just showing that to illustrate.  
@JasonWells yes same as any function you can call your parameter anything you like the first param is data passed back from server second is status code and third is `jqXHR` (which i don't know what that is)

Comment: @JasonWells If you don't understand the "done()" concept, read up on [.Deferred and Promise](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/).

Comment: @dm03514 FYI, getName("1").done(buildRow(response)) does not work. I get a "response not defined" :( - so we have to use an anon function.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
//Example: Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});

//Example: Retrieve the latest version of an HTML page.
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
  $("#results").append(html);
});
```

Also, make sure you read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types), because, depending on the Datatype you might actually "receive" not a simple string/id but possibly an object parsed from a JSON/XML result or...

Comment: Well, I am returning JSON in my example.

Comment: Then add a `console.log(myvar);` so you can inspect `myvar` (assuming you named the parameter `myvar` that is). Then you can drill into `myvar` and see which properties it has / which one you need of want to use etc. You access the console by pressing `Ctrl-Shift-J` in Chrome or `F12` in Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Roblll, it was helpful. I still cannot find much documentation on whether or not we can do getFoo().done(getBar(response)); as I get a "response undefined". I can do getFoo().done(function(response){getBar(response)}); - it's just not as clean :p